# How to find a subset of given cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reviewing earlier exams and found this question:

If we let $U = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7, a, b, c, d, e\}, A =\{2,4, b, c\}$ and $B = \{2,3,6,7, b, d, e\}$.

What are all the subsets of A with cardinality 3 and with $b$ an element of the subset?

Comment: Well since it has to have cardinality three and already has one element you can add two more. So out of the three remaining members you can pick any two so you have 3 combinations. Shouldn't be hard to list them.

Comment: -1 for changing the question completely, esp after others have provided answers.

Comment: @achillehui I rolled back to the previous version.

Comment: Can it be talken for granted, that $b\ne 2$, $b\ne 4$, $c\ne 2$, $c\ne 4$, $b\ne c$? NB, $\{x,x\}=\{x\}$.

Comment: Please **do not** deface your question after receiving an answer. Doing so disrespects the users who have taken their time to provide you with answers. Continuing to do so....

Answer (score 1):

Subsets with cardinality 3 have 3 elements, and $b$ is one of them. You need all subsets of $A$ with $b$ and two more elements. Eor example, $\{2,4,b\}$. Can you list them all?

Answer (score 0):

all the subsets of A with cardinality 3 and with b  an element of the subset are:{2,4,b},{2,b,c},{4,b,c}